# "I'm having" - an illness?

Tags: grammar, terminology

What is *I'm having* in grammar terms? Is it something near the present, the near future? As in *I'm having a party tomorrow*?

Example (not about the near future),

> I'm having trouble coming up with a reliable method of comparing sets of data.

Couldn't it be the following simpler version without any change in meaning?

> I have trouble coming up with a reliable method of comparing sets of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am having trouble* is written using the *present continuous tense* (also called *present progressive tense*).

The progressive tenses are used to put emphasis on the described event being in progress; the progressive also indicates habitual actions (*I am walking a lot more now*).

The interpretation that I would give to the sentences you wrote is

- "I'm having trouble coming up with a reliable method of comparing sets of data." — you are searching a reliable method also in the moment you are saying/writing that.
- "I have trouble coming up with a reliable method of comparing sets of data." — You cannot find a reliable method for comparing sets of data and you are searching a reliable method when you are saying/writing that, or you stopped searching for such method.

There is a difference between *I have trouble* and *I had trouble*, as the latter one means that you found a way to compare sets of data in a reliable way (and your trouble is done).

Comment: "I'm having trouble" means that my difficulty is current and (hopefully) temporary; "I have trouble" means that this is something with which I habitually have difficulty.

Answer (score 5):

*Am having* is the [present continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html) tense and *have* is the [simple present](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html) tense of the verb *to have*.

In the question, the first sentence means that I am having trouble now while the second sentence means that I usually have trouble coming up with a reliable method of comparing sets of data. The present continuous tense is also used to talk about something that will happen in the near future. For example:

> I am going home tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to touch on your description: **I'm having an illness**.

It seems the progressive is not used with illnesses, at least not in the UK. Medical problems should instead be referred to using **have** in the **simple present tense**. Therefore, we should say:

> I have a cold.

rather than

> I am having a cold.

**I'm having a cold** may imply other ridiculous meanings such as:

1. eating or drinking:

   > having dinner/ having a cold (eating
   >   dinner/eating a cold)
2. hosting a social occasion:

   > having a party/having a cold (hosting
   >   or giving a party/ hosting or giving a
   >   cold)

When I was at university, my English flatmates laughed at me when I said **"I'm having a cold."** That stuck with me ever since. [No pity votes, please.  :-)]

Comment: +1 Good answer. I just read the question and forgot about the title. Here's a link to a page about stative verbs: http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-explained/stative-verbs

Comment: @Tragicomic: Thanks for the upvote and the link, good one. I like the section for kids.